# Python: call C function with sudo

Tags: python, sudo

My python script is using Extensions to call another C function which has to be run with sudo. I can call the fucntion successfully from plain python script:

```
sudo python my_py_scr.py
```

while "my_py_scr.py" contains the following

```
import MyModule
MyModule.mymethod("in_arg")
```

Now I have further developed this "my_py_scr.py" to execute other function, so SOMEHOW it looks like:

```
import MyModule
from rgbmatrix import RGBMatrix, RGBMatrixOptions

#... some definitions

self.matrix = RGBMatrix(options = options)
MyModule.mymethod("in_arg")
```

The problem now is: *MyModule.mymethod* is not calling the embedded C function as it needs root privilage. I got the following error message

```
Must run as root to be able to access /dev/mem
Prepend 'sudo' to the command
```

I am running this code in RaspberryPi. I hope if someone understands why when I add

```
self.matrix = RGBMatrix(options = options)
```

the sudo privilage is not passed to

```
MyModule.mymethod("in_arg")
```

Comment: what if you run `mymethod` before `RGBMatrix` or at the beginning of script, or even before importing `RGBMatrix` ?

Comment: @furas if I run mymethod before RGBMatrix, everything goes well

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the error message is misleading .. the problem is not in the sudo credentials but in the access of /dev/mem ..

since I am working on Raspberry Pi, both functions (mymethod & RGBMatrix) were trying to access GPIO of Raspberry. So mymethod is not able to access the GPIO as it is locked.